# How to make arhitecture for integration tests and microservices in Node.js

Tags: javascript, docker, continuous-integration, integration-testing, microservices

I have created microservice app.

Every microservice is unit tested.

Now, before I start to build frontend and more complex integrations, I would like to make integration servers using docker.

I know how to create docker-compose fie that will spin all my services for testing, but I dont know how do you run integration tests?

do you create another service for testing, and then inside you call `jest /integration` or do you approach it with docker commands?

right now, I created one service just for unit test, to see if everything is correctly setup docker wise, and everything works.

I would like to automate everything so that when I push on bitbucket, I can connect my repository either with bitbucket pipelines or better yet docker-hub to run my tests, both unit and integration ones.

Comment: Couldn't the integration tests just run from the application container where you hook up the service dependencies in docker-compose? Unless you are talking a fully end to end test which you can also do by changing the host for the integration tests if you need to do it in QA.

Comment: My current solution is to create a container that will run integration tests, it will depend on other services so it will start at the end

Comment: So I guess the main question is running the tests within the container or outside the container? Inside the container gives you some benefits such as being not having to install package dependencies for the tests in your local environment and it could be well isolated for various environments so I don't see why not if thats your main question. The way I would set it up is either to use multi-stage builds for the image you're going to deploy and separate images that may include test dependencies to run the tests (both unit and integration).

Comment: I would accept this answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running the tests inside the container gives some added benefits such as not having to install dependencies for the tests in the local environment and isolating the potential for environment specific problems.

An additional feature of Docker that you can look into is multi-stage builds for the deploy image and separate images that include test dependencies that run for both unit and integration tests. That way the image that gets deployed a smaller and doesn't include potential unnecessary test dependencies.

One other thing to note is that you might want to parameterize the test runs with environment variable that determine the host, ports or user accounts so that you can run the tests using the proper credentials for different environments.